# POST from an <A> tag

Tags: html, post

Is it possible to do a POST from just an `<a>` tag? I know anchor tags are usually just for GETs, and I know I can use javascript to do this (like in [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)) but to me that seems a little messy. Is there a way to do this with straight HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a link use POST instead of GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no way to `POST` an `a` element using only HTML.

As can be seen from this DTD fragment ([HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-href)):

```
<!ELEMENT A - - (%inline;)* -(A)       -- anchor -->
<!ATTLIST A
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED  -- char encoding of linked resource --
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED  -- advisory content type --
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- named link end --
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- URI for linked resource --
  hreflang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED  -- language code --
  rel         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED  -- forward link types --
  rev         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED  -- reverse link types --
  accesskey   %Character;    #IMPLIED  -- accessibility key character --
  shape       %Shape;        rect      -- for use with client-side image maps --
  coords      %Coords;       #IMPLIED  -- for use with client-side image maps --
  tabindex    NUMBER         #IMPLIED  -- position in tabbing order --
  onfocus     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element got the focus --
  onblur      %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element lost the focus --
  >
```

There is no attribute that controls whether to use `POST` or `GET` with an `a` element.

You *have* to script it, if you want to abuse the semantics.

Comment: I like how you concluded with "if you want to abuse the semantics", i.e **one shouldn't do this** and should use the recommended way of doing such things, i.e using a `form` to submit data.

Answer (score 44):

Not really, no. You can, however, do something like this:

```
<form action="theUrl" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="param1" value="val" />
<input type="hidden" name="param2" value="val2" />

<a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">Go to that link!</a>

</form>
```

You should find a better way, though. This one does not degrade gracefully.

Comment: onclick="this.parentNode.submit()" should be 

onclick="event.preventDefault(); this.parentNode.submit()" using jQuery.

It will be better.

Comment: @ThếAnhNguyễn: Hardly matters, since the form is being submitted. Again, ideally, you would not do this at all, and style a button to look like a link instead.

Answer (score 15):

Basically, you can't use an anchor tag for a POST request. However, there is a simple hack to achieve this.

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="target.html"></form>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();">Submit to action</a>
```

Tested and working fine.

Answer (score 14):

You can use CSS to make an `<input type="submit">` look like a hyperlink.

Comment: @VGE: Yes, but this can accomplish what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 8):

In case it serves somebody:

```
<a href="/your-route"
    onclick="event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('magic-form').submit();">
    Magic Action
</a>
<form id="magic-form" action="/your-route" 
      method="POST" style="display: none;">
      {{ csrf_field() }} <!-- from your framework -->
      <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="value1" />
      <!-- other fields -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: no. You need to use javascript to do this kind of thing; since when you do a POST what you're doing is sending the data in the HTTP request. With get you're just sending it as part of the string (thus you can do it through the `href` value).

Answer (score 1):

You can use htmx for this https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-post/

For example:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.2" integrity="sha384-L6OqL9pRWyyFU3+/bjdSri+iIphTN/bvYyM37tICVyOJkWZLpP2vGn6VUEXgzg6h" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a hx-post="/account/enable"/>Some text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No clearly not without a javascript submit().

Answer (score 0):

No there's no way to do this without the use of scripting. Although you can use CSS to style a standard Submit button to look and act more like an  tag.

Answer (score -1):

The 2 ways I think about are with JavaScript (as you said) or through server-scription.

You'd basically send the GET request (with the A) to some server file, which would change the GET vars to POST and then re-submit instantly (redirect location).  But that would mess the referer stats I think.

Answer (score -3):

You should to add data-method="post"

For example: `<a href="/some-link" data-method="post">Logout</a>`