# How to postback from an anchor tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an achor tag from which I want to postback to my controller action.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName","Home",FormMethod.Post))
        {        
            <div class="toolbar_button">                        
                @{

                    var Route = Url.Action("ActionName", "Home");
                    var Anchor = MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("<a href=\"\"><img src=\"../../Content/Images/image.png\"></img>stringname</a>"));
                 }
                @Anchor
            </div>
        }
```

I do have a controller function which defined

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(viewModel)
{
}
```

Whenever I m clicking the anchor tag, it is not coming to this action.

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6180256/360053.

Comment: Don't use the word postback. Postback is form WebForm and it is not the same thing as a HTTP POST.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one form on the page you can add onclick handler to the A-tag: document.forms[0].submit()

Another, preferred way to achieve this would be to add an input element with type submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
```

Comment: Actually the view consists of multiple partial views.

Comment: Views are not the same as forms. As long as there's only one <form> element on the page, it should work. If there are multiple forms on the page, I'd suggest adding a <input type="submit" ... /> to each one.

Comment: Is there anyway to include the image with the input type?

Comment: Yes, you can use <button> element. Check out this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/avjYu/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot POST with a plain link.

Here is some options:

- Submit the form (use a submit button or JavaScript - calling submit on the form -, etc.)
- AJAX... Example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/