# redirecting form jsp in Web-inf to servlet in javaResources through href in

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my **Login.jsp** page

```
<form name="login" action="ValidateServlet" method="post">  
<input type="hidden" name="pagename" value="login"/>   
<table>  

<tr>  
<td><b>USERNAME:</b><input type="text" name="txtUsername"/> </td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
<td><b>PASSWORD:</b><input type="password" name="txtPassword"/></td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
<td><input type="SUBMIT" value="SIGN IN"/></td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
<td><a href= "/PasswordServlet">Forgot Password</a></td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td><a href= "/SignUp"> Create New user </a></td>  
</tr>  
</table>  
</form>`
```

And this is my **SignupServlet**:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response throws          
 ServletException, IOException {  
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/WebPages/Signup.jsp");  
 rd.forward(request, response);  
}  

}
```

and this is my web.xml

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>SignupServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.affiliate.servlet.SignupServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>SignupServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/SignUp</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Login.jsp** is in `Webcontent/WEB-INF/WebPages/Login.jsp`
and **SignupServlet** in `JavaResources/src/com.affiliate.servlet/SignupServlet`
but my Login is not redirecting to the SignupServlet. And i have doubt on my href and form action. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but you consistently refer to the jsp as `Login.jsp` but the servlet refers to `Signup.jsp` - please recheck the names of all the involved components.  Also, as you map the servlet to `/SignUp` why `<form name="login" action="ValidateServlet" method="post">` ?

Comment: remove web-inf `protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response throws          
     ServletException, IOException {  
     RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WebPages/Signup.jsp");  
     rd.forward(request, response);  
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<a href= "/SignUp"> Create New user </a>
          ↑
```

To

```
<a href= "SignUp"> Create New user </a>
```

---

And in [anchor tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2) there is no `post` method available. You need to change the code in `SignupServlet`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response throws          
  ServletException, IOException 
{  
   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Signup.jsp");  
   rd.forward(request, response);  
}
```

If you want `post` request using `a` tag then refer [POST from an  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6180256/1031945)

Comment: this is the error am getting on changing my code as u said                                                                   type Status report

message /Affiliate/WebPages/Signup.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: @user3222718 : That means it is redirecting now, and just not able to find the Signup.jsp file. See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response throws          
 ServletException, IOException {  
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/WebPages/Signup.jsp");  
 rd.forward(request, response);  
}
```

to

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response throws          
 ServletException, IOException {  
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/WebPages/Signup.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: @fvu my login page is a form which on providing username and password will redirect to validateServlet for further processing. and same in the Login form i have two hrefs one is if the user has forgotten his/her password will click on forgotPassword which will direct him to some servlet. and on pressing create new user it will redirect to SignupServlet and SignupServlet has a dispatcher to redirect to Signup.jsp. Both Login.jsp and Signup.jsp are in WEB-INF/WebPages directory but i have a servlet to redirect it from login.jsp to Signup.jsp for security purpose

Comment: Thank u all i got it by changing                             `protected void  doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response throws          
 ServletException, IOException {  
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WebPages/Signup.jsp").forward(request, response);
} `to                                                      `protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response throws          
 ServletException, IOException {  
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/WebPages/Signup.jsp").forward(request, response);
} `

Comment: looks lyk I was the closest except for the web-inf

Comment: oh sorry i didnt get how to write a code in this forum in comment am a newbie sorry all and thank you very much and thank you @Aniket for informing me about doGet() method in href it worked...

Comment: You will need to close this question since its answered..by giving a tick to the right one

Comment: oh my i cant tick 2 so i give my vote to Aniket and @user3040563.... Thank you both for your valid answers... Bye

Answer (score 0):

```
replace

<a href= "/PasswordServlet">Forgot Password</a> 
<a href= "/SignUp"> Create New user </a>
```

To

```
<a href= "PasswordServlet">Forgot Password</a> 
<a href= "SignUp"> Create New user </a>
```

---

```
Remove "/" before Servlet URL Pattern
```

Comment: Thats what I posted 12 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

In your login.jsp call SignUp servlet in following way

```
<td><a href= "SignUp"> Create New user </a></td>
```

and In SignUp servlet in your doGet method

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/webpages/Signup.jsp");  
         rd.forward(request, response);
```

Because when you call a servlet from a link or href it the doGet method gets run. Hope this helps