# How to send an  HTTP POST method through a link href?

Tags: http, express, nodes, middleware

I have the following link and want to issue a `POST` method instead of default `GET` method.

```
<li><a href="/logout">logout</a></li>
```

I know `connect` has a `methodOverride` middleware to handle form submission methods but it doesn't help with normal link href.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a link use POST instead of GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid showing variabiles that you pass through regular GET, I would suggest using `<input type="button" />` instead of `<a href="#"></a>`, and some hidden inputs as well to pass the data, and process that wherever you want.

I mean, I don't see any other reason for someone to want to change GET method in anchors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't; this is not what HTML anchors are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript. just bind  click event to the link and do an ajax post request.

I would recommend using [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript to do this. Ruby on Rails has a javascript library that you can use for that.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

If you import that you can do

```
<a href='/stuff' data-method='delete'>destroy</a>
```

I would use delete for logging out because you are destroying/deleting a session.