# POST method for Clickable URL

Tags: http

We have a simple user database with user email contacts. The email needs to be verified. We send a verification code in the form of a clickable URL which user can click to verify their email. The clicked URL results in a GET call whereas we need it to make a POST instead. Is this possible?

In simple words: user sees a normal http://.... URL, which when clicked results in a POST instead of the usual GET.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a link use POST instead of GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get)

Comment: No, you can't.

You can instead let the page you GET, POST to the final page.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately the server cannot retrieve the verification code. My only suggestion is to header("Location: x"); on the page where they click at the footer. ;D