# How to identify how a page fetches variables from a form with $_POST

Tags: forms, url, post

I'm trying to understand how a courier company - DawnWing - fetches information from the `Where is my parcel` block at the top of the page on [their website](http://www.dawnwing.co.za/).

On inspection, I can see the following information:

```
<form action="/business-tools/online-parcel-tracking/" method="post" style="margin:0;" _lpchecked="1">
    <span class="icons search-icon"></span>
    <span style="float:left;">Where is <br> my Parcel?</span>
    <input maxlength="13" name="WaybillNo" type="text" style="float:left; margin-left:5px; width:100px;" placeholder="1234567890">
    <input type="submit" name="parcel-search" value="go" style="float:left; margin-left:5px;">
</form>
```

The page it directs to is:

```
http://www.dawnwing.co.za/business-tools/online-parcel-tracking/
```

How can I simulate a direct link to this page with the search having already been conducted?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should learn the difference between GET and POST HTTP request. [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get).

Comment: Sorry if I made it unclear. I understand that with POST you will not have access to the variable. I'm hoping to establish though how I can simulate a link which takes you to the page with the search already conducted. I've updated my question to make this a little more clear.

Comment: You can't create a link to a POST resource. Using some sort of JS you can land there by creating a form which points to the same URL and passing the same POST parameter, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get)

Comment: @mTorres thanks, will check it out. Don't know why these guys opted to use something like POST on a waybill submission form, would make it so much more convenient to link your customers directly to their tracking page.