# How do I make a link use POST method in Yii?

Tags: php, yii2

In Rails we can do

```
= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :post
```

How do we achieve this in Yii? (Without having to manually create a hidden form: [Make a link use POST instead of GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get).)

I looked through the guide for `Url` for `post`, but couldn't find anything.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html

So far I have this

```
%a.btn.btn-sm.btn-success{href: Url::to(['update-bid', 'change' => 'plus'])} +10%
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19380-using-chtmllink-with-post-parameters/

Comment: @anantkumarsingh That's for Yii1. What about Yii2? Yii2 doesn't have `Chtml`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?= Html::a('submit', Url::to(['site/index']), ['data-method' => 'POST']) ?>
```

Comment: Wow is that an undocumented feature of Yii? What's creating the hidden form? Is that part of jQuery?

Comment: HAML version: `%a.btn.btn-sm.btn-success{href: Url::to(['increase-bid']), 'data-method' => 'POST'} +10%`

Comment: You can find the documentation of this feature at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#common-asset-bundles

Answer (score 20):

Folllow code for creating link based **Post Link**

```
<?= Html::a('Text', 
['/controller/action'], [
'data-method' => 'POST',
'data-params' => [
    'param1' => 1,
    'param2' => 2,
],
]) ?>
```

And then u can access these variables in controller

```
public function actionAction () {
   $param1 = Yii::$app->request->post('param1', null);
   $param2 = Yii::$app->request->post('param2', null);
}
```

For batter detail information follow below link
[Click Here](http://www.prettyscripts.com/code/php/yii2-posting-data-via-link/)