# Laravel 5. Dont work put and delete methods

Tags: routes, laravel-5, put

Today stopped working `DELETE` and `PUT` methods with link_to_route

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Route:

```
Route::put('inits/{init_id}/publication', ['as' => 'init.publication', 'uses' =>'Inits\InitsController@putPublicationInit']);
```

Blade:

```
{!! link_to_route('init.publication',
        'Publication',
        $init->id,
        ['class' => 'btn btn-control gray-lighter',
        'data-method' => 'put',
        'data-token' => csrf_token()]
) !!}
```

`DELETE` methods leads to `GET`.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a link that will make a POST request. All Links are GET requests. Use form or javascript to trigger a POST/DELETE/PUT request when the link is clicked.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get) a question with an example of how to accomplish that.

Comment: You must have had the link in a form or some javascript that ran with it. `'data-method' => 'put', 'data-token' => csrf_token()` with this code I would assume you have some javascript that converts clicks to ajax requests.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I found it.
laravel.js was included https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/5112282

Answer (score 0):

For DELETE, POST and PUT requests, you need to use a form request.

You are generating a simple link, which will lead to a GET request on the page.

Have a look at the doc : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing

Hope it helps