# C#, Asp.Net. Is there any other way to pass data without Query string.

Tags: c#, html, database

I've database record in HTML Table and having a hyperlink 'Edit'. I want to pass data by clicking on Edit link, the selected row and ID of that Data should be show on another page without querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an other way. If you make a POST instead of of a GET. This way the data you want to pass will be included in the body of the request and not in the query string.

How can you do this? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get) is a great way to do so.