# how to convert curl to http or link - mailgun

Tags: sendmail, mailgun

how i can send mail by direct link.
code:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
-F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
-F to=YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
-F to=bar@example.com \
-F subject='Hello' \
-F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
```

Can anyone convert this code to link

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable `to` two times, each variable can be there only once. Otherwise it would look like this:

`https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages?from=%27Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>%27&to=bar@example.com&subject=%27Hello%27&text=%27Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!%27`

Comment: thanks but it's return Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: Ok, the request needs to be a POST request, not a GET request. You will have to create a hidden form on the page and then send it with JavaScript. See the answer in this post to get forward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get

Comment: thanks , how i can me create module in vb.net to sendmail ?

Comment: If you use mailgun, you won't need sendmail. Just create a HTML form and trigger it to submit form a button, as in the previous comment's link.

Comment: mailgun it's send just for my email i want send for all people

Comment: You need to have a mail server, such as sendmail and a web server, such as Apache in front of the mail server to relay the GET/POST requests from the browser to the mail server. `Browser --> Web server --> Mail server --> Recipient`