# Make POST request from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, post

I want to make an HTTP POST request from an HTML anchor tag that has the URL in its href attribute.
How can I make it use POST instead of GET?

```
<a href='http:/test_url:5002/api/GetFile'></a>
```

I also want to set parameters in the body of the request. How can I do that?
I want to find a way to include them in the HTML tag itself, not in a JavaScript file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a link use POST instead of GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get)

Answer (score 0):

Links are designed to GET a URL. You cannot make a POST request directly with them.

Use a form with a submit button instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what forms are for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form
Just create a form with a submit button. You can also specify if you want to open the requested URL in a new tab with the `target` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you could do it

```
 <form  method="POST" action="/api/PostFile">

<!-- with input in between -->


<!-- and a submit button--> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's only one way for you to `POST` data with a link... you would need to wrap the code in a `<form>` and use that link to submit the form, for example:

```html
<form id="frm" ation="http:/test_url:5002/api/GetFile">
  <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value_for_param1" />
  ...
  <a href="#" onclick="document.querySelector('#frm').submit()"></a>
  ...
</form>
```

any `input` can be used to append parameters to the `<form>`, as an example, the `hidden` is used

now, remember that you shouldn't use `http:/test_url:5002` just minimize to `/api/getfile` or you would most likely get caught into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues